# OpenCV error: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'M'

Tags: python, opencv, opencl

I'm new to Python, therefore having troubles with debugging a script. I'm trying to create an '[average face](https://www.learnopencv.com/average-face-opencv-c-python-tutorial/)' using an `opencv` script to recreate with my own images. [Here's the Github repo](https://github.com/stekhn/average-faces-opencv) I'm using, but same goes for [this one](https://github.com/lalet/Average-Face) and [this one](https://github.com/andrewjeminchoi/simple-face-average).

The land mark detection part works but the `average.py` script throws the error I don't understand how to solve.

The first two errors I solved by replacing the `xrange()` function with `range()`. Than the `estimateRigidTransform()` seemed depricated and there for I swapped it with `estimateAffinePartial2D()` so far so good.

Now the console throws me the following error:

`TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'M'`

This is the scripts' code snippet:

```
# Apply affine transform calculated using src_tri and dst_tri to src and
# output an image of size.
def apply_affine_transform(src, src_tri, dst_tri, size):

    # Given a pair of triangles, find the affine transform.
    warp_mat = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(src_tri), np.float32(dst_tri))

    # Apply the Affine Transform just found to the src image
    dst = cv2.warpAffine(src, warp_mat, (size[0], size[1]), None,
        flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)

    return dst
```

For more reproducible code see repos in introduction of this question.

All help much appreciated!

Comment: Two things: First, I believe reading somewhere that `opencv` recommends Python 3.x over Python 2.x. Second, I had that same error when some variables are not `np.array` of correct types. You might want to check the types of `t1_rect, t2_rect` on the call of `apply_affine_trasform` on line 294.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `tform = cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(np.array([inPts]), np.array([outPts]))` and returning `tform`, return `tform[0]`.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad767faff73e9cbd8b9d92b955b50062d) for more details.

You will notice that `estimateAffinePartial2D` returns `retVal` and `inliers`. That's why when you are returning `tform`, you are getting a `TypeError`.

I have also created a PR to fix the code on our LearnOpenCV GitHub repository.

Vishwesh

**Edit**: You can check the PR [here](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/pull/270).

Comment: Awesome thanks, that works! Can you tell me how to save the image output in `.jpg` or `.png`?

Comment: Yeah. You can use `cv2.imwrite` function.